# Valid HTTPS certificate with Docker and Traefik

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to create a local website using **Docker Compose** and **Traefik**. I was able to create the HTTPS domain, but the generated certificate is not valid as you can see in the following image

[image]

This is the configuration of my services

[image]
[image]

You can access the code here: https://gist.github.com/jdeg/6b9cd5283d71edf3304ab9d0a9cce75d

What is the correct way to create a **valid** certificate with Docker Compose and Traefik?

Comment: stackoverflow rules: paste relevant config directly into the question (don't force others to follow links). my guess is `letsencrypt` either failed or didn't succeed yet. please trace that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I checked the logs and got this message "traefik Domain name does not end with a valid public suffix (TLD)" then searched in the letsencrypt forum and found this comment: "you can’t get a certificate with a private domain name. You need a public visible and unique domain name to get a certificate.".